# SQL Query Average in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is the table:

Faculty:

```
    School_ID char(3), 
    Fac_LastName char(15), 
    Fac_FirstName char(15), 
    Fac_DOB char(15), 
    Fac_SS# char(15), 
    Fac_Address char(15), 
    Fac_City char(15), 
    Fac_State char(2), 
    Fac_Zip char(5), 
    Fac_salary numeric(8,2)
```

query :  **Show instructors whose salaries are above an average.**

I run following query in Microsoft Access:

```
SELECT Avg(FACULTY.Fac_salary) AS average, FACULTY.Fac_LastName
FROM FACULTY
GROUP BY FACULTY.Fac_LastName
HAVING (((FACULTY.Fac_salary) >Avg([FACULTY].[Fac_salary])));
```

**but its giving and error that (((FACULTY.Fac_salary) >Avg([FACULTY].[Fac_salary]))) is not a part of aggreggate function.**

Kindly keep your answer specific to Microsoft Access

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the comparative average is for all records in table `FACULTY`, you will need to calculate the overall average separately, before you can determine which members exceed this average.

You can do this like so:

```
SELECT FACULTY.Fac_LastName, FACULTY.Fac_salary
FROM FACULTY
WHERE ((FACULTY.Fac_salary) > (SELECT Avg(FACULTY.Fac_salary) FROM FACULTY));
```