# SQL Access Query to Display names of Youngest Students

Tags: sql, ms-access

Write a query:
**Display the first and last names of the youngest students.**

for the following table:
`STUDENT
(School_ID char(3), St_LastName char(15), St_FirstName char(15), St_DOB char(15), St_SS# char(15), St_Address char(15),St_City char(15), St_State char(2),st_Zip char(5), st_phone char(15));`
Its working but not executing values

SELECT STUDENT.St_FirstName,STUDENT.St_DOB
FROM STUDENT,
(
 SELECT  MAX(STUDENT.St_DOB) AS maximum
   FROM FACULTY
)AS YOUNG
WHERE ((STUDENT.St_DOB) <(YOUNG.maximum));

Your answer should be specific in Microsoft Access

Comment: You'll need to show what you've tried (your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515525/sql-query-average-in-microsoft-access) showed some good effort).

Comment: ok sure.Let me try this

Comment: i have tried this but again same error

Comment: SELECT STUDENT.St_FirstName,STUDENT.St_DOB
FROM STUDENT,
(
 SELECT  MAX(STUDENT.St_DOB) AS max
   FROM FACULTY
)AS YOUNG
WHERE ((STUDENT.St_DOB) < MAX(YOUNG.max));

Comment: its working but not return values:   SELECT STUDENT.St_FirstName,STUDENT.St_DOB
FROM STUDENT,
(
 SELECT  MAX(STUDENT.St_DOB) AS maximum
   FROM FACULTY
)AS YOUNG
WHERE ((STUDENT.St_DOB) <(YOUNG.maximum));

Comment: @UsmanShafiArain - why you are not using 'DATETIME' data type for St_DOB ?

Comment: @FathahRehmanP char datatype is requirement in my assignment

Answer (score 0):

Write a query to convert St_DOB to date using MS Access `CDate` function. And sort result in the descending order of that date. Then the first row of result contain youngest student. I dont have ms access now. Otherwise i'll show the actual query.