# Add a column of Averages in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have written the below query to show total calls (from phone system) coming in for individual days of the week. What I now need is to show the average of the total calls coming in for these days.

My query look like this:

```
SELECT WeekdayName(Weekday([Calls Volume].Weekday),False,1) AS [Day of the week], Sum([Calls Volume].Offered) AS [Calls Offered]
FROM [Calls Volume]
GROUP BY WeekdayName(Weekday([Calls Volume].Weekday),False,1), [Calls Volume].Weekday
ORDER BY [Calls Volume].Weekday;
```

Current Output:

```
Day of the week | Calls Offered
--------------------------------
Monday          | 100

Tuesday         | 200

Wednesday       | 300
```

Desired output:

```
Day of the week | Calls Offered  |  Average Calls for the day of the week
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Monday          | 100            | 30

Tuesday         | 200            | 20

Wednesday       | 300            | 15
```

Thanks
Sample data:

```
DateTime | Calls Offered
------------------------ 
1/08/2014 9AM | 12 

1/08/2014 10AM | 10

2/08/2014 9AM | 9 

2/08/2014 11AM | 12
```

and so forth..

Comment: `..Sum([Calls Volume].Offered) AS [Calls Offered],Avg([Calls Volume].Offered) as [average calls]..`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515525/sql-query-average-in-microsoft-access

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my scenario, there is a problem with averaging this way. The [Calls Volume] table has multiple records of calls for any given day in 30 mins increments. Your solution would have been perfect if there was only one total for each day which is not the case.

For ex:
DateTime | Calls Offered
------------------------
1/08/2014 9AM | 12
1/08/2014 10AM | 10
2/08/2014 9AM | 9
2/08/2014 11AM | 12

Comment: Put the data in the question,this is hard to read

Comment: As far as I can see the problem is different grades of granularity so in the main query you group by WEEKDAY but in your average column I think you would need an AVG of calls but this time GROUP by WEEKDAY,AND the time portion of the date time.So try it with a subquery JOINed to the main query.

Comment: Yes, I can see the problem. I have removed the time stamp from the date field and now I only have 4 or 5 Weekdaynames for every month. Can you assist me in showing how to write a subquery for this? Thanks